# google gcm not sending messges with PushSharp as my server

Tags: c#, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I have everything set up and working on the android device.  It retrieves a, what I think to be, valid token and then passes it to my server where it's stored in a database.

I'm then using the PushSharp library to push out my messages to my device.  I know that PushSharp is connecting successfully to google because if I enter an invalid server key, I get a not authorized exception.  The OnNotificationSent event is firing and I'm logging that result with NLog and it says it's sending my notification successfully.  I am however NOT receiving my notifications to my Evo 4g phone.  I've tried two Evo 4g's with the same result.  I am logged into my google account on both phones and when I run the android app on one, the device token is updated to that devices token, then I run it on the other, and it changes, so that all appears to be in order.

when I look on the google api dashboard at the reports section it says I've had 0 total requests.  In all honesty, I'm not even sure that is what it's supposed to report there, but I can only assume it reports any messages that have gone through the service.

Am I missing a setting somewhere on the google api to "turn it on" or something?

I've been fighting the android side of this for the better part of the day and finally got it going about 2 hours ago.  I have PushSharp working for apple notifications and for all intents and purposes, it looks like it should be working with google gcm, but it's not.

any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this sorted.  I wasn't handling the notification in the onMessage properly.

Comment: Please ,can you provide more information about your solution.
really , I am facing the exactly same problem, as you described.

Comment: It's been a few years since I posted this so I don't recall exactly what my underlying issue was.  Where are you stuck?  Are the messages getting to your phone?